# Avoid report to allow modifications of records in Filemaker Pro 11

Tags: list, report, filemaker

I'm building a database that needs to display tables as lists and allow the user to export such lists as Excel spreadsheets.
Creating the reports, showing them as lists and providing the button for exporting as Excel was not a problem, however I noticed that when I show those lists the user can still edit them, hence add/deleting records and modify the content of existing records.
I'd like to find a way to avoid such modifications when visualizing the list, in such a way to be sure the user does not accidentally change data.

Any idea as to how to do this? I'm using Filemaker pro 11

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you'd consider rephrasing your question? I, for one, am having a hard time understanding what help you're asking for.

Comment: You're probably right -- apologies. I'll edit end rephrase...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways that might be appropriate, depending on your needs:

1. In layout mode, click on the field, go to the Data tab of the Inspector, and turn off **field entry in 'Browse' mode**. (You also have the option to turn off field entry in 'Find' mode. And you can select multiple fields at once to make the selection for all of them.) This is appropriate if your users can regularly enter data into these fields but you don't want them to enter data for *this particular layout*.
2. In Manage Database, under the field options, turn on **Prohibit modification of value during data entry** in the Auto-Enter tab. This is appropriate if you will only be changing the value of a field during an import or with a script.
3. In Manage Security, create a new Privilege Set that is View-Only for that table (or for those fields). This is appropriate when some users *should* be able to modify the data and other users *should not* be able to modify the data.

There are other methods, as well, but those are the three most common for limiting user access to data.